# Testing Probabilities in SAS: Chi square test with a Composite Null

Tags: sas, statistics, chi-squared

I'm doing some research for my Masters thesis using SAS, and I'm slightly stuck on something. The test I'm trying to run has a one-sided Null Hypothesis with my basic assertion that the underlying population probability should be *greater* than 0.5

Using a Proc Freq procedure with the following syntax helps me test if the probability is *equal to* 0.5 or not

```
proc freq data=data;
    tables Var1 / nocum chisq testp=(50 50);
run;
```

How should I check the original null that the value should be *greater than* 0.5 and not merely *equal to* 0.5?

My sample probabilities are what I expect them to be, but the p values are almost double to what I expect.

Comment: Look at the BINOMIAL option.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you!